# Making multiple VertexPositionColor variables in the same class? - XNA

Tags: xna, c#, vertex, vertex-buffer

I have studying XNA on my spare time for about a year now and I could use some professional help on this issue. Any time given to my problem is appreciated.

I have two VertexPositionColor variables both of which are placed into two separate vertex buffers to draw up three triangles

```
basicEffect = new BasicEffect(GraphicsDevice);
        VertexPositionColor[] vertices = new VertexPositionColor[6];
        vertices[0] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0, 1, 0), Color.Red); 
        vertices[1] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(-1, -1, 0), Color.Green); 
        vertices[2] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(1, -1, 0), Color.Blue); 
        vertices[3] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0.05f, 1, 0), Color.Yellow);
        vertices[4] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(-1, -1, 0), Color.Blue);
        vertices[5] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(-1, 1, 0), Color.Pink);
        vertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(GraphicsDevice, typeof(VertexPositionColor), 6, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
        vertexBuffer.SetData<VertexPositionColor>(vertices);

        VertexPositionColor[] vertices2 = new VertexPositionColor[3];
        vertices2[0] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0, 1, 0), Color.Blue); 
        vertices2[1] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(-1, -1, 0), Color.Red); 
        vertices2[2] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0.9f, -0.9f, 0), Color.Orange);
        vertexBuffer2 = new VertexBuffer(GraphicsDevice, typeof(VertexPositionColor), 6, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
        vertexBuffer2.SetData<VertexPositionColor>(vertices2);
```

I then use the draw function to draw all three triangles ..

```
public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        basicEffect.World = world;
        basicEffect.View = view;
        basicEffect.Projection = projection;
        basicEffect.VertexColorEnabled = true;
        GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer);
        GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer2);
        RasterizerState rasterizerState = new RasterizerState();
        rasterizerState.CullMode = CullMode.None;
        GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = rasterizerState;
        foreach (EffectPass pass in basicEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
        {
            pass.Apply();
            GraphicsDevice.DrawPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 3);

        }
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

But it does not draw all three triangles. I have tried various variations and all that gets drawn is either the last vertex buffer or the first one. I know it would be more efficient to place them all in the same buffer or have them used with indices, but in the future I will run into issues where I am going to need more than one buffer to draw something and I want to be prepared. What is the problem here and how do I draw more than one vertex buffer at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do your draw calls for each vertex buffer you set, with the corresponding number of primitives as the third parameter in *DrawPrimitives*. Calling *GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer* two times will replace the first vertex buffer.

Your draw function should look similar to this:

```
public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    basicEffect.World = world;
    basicEffect.View = view;
    basicEffect.Projection = projection;
    basicEffect.VertexColorEnabled = true;
    RasterizerState rasterizerState = new RasterizerState();
    rasterizerState.CullMode = CullMode.None;
    GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = rasterizerState;
    GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer);
    foreach (EffectPass pass in basicEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
    {
        pass.Apply();
        GraphicsDevice.DrawPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 2);

    }
    GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer2);
    foreach (EffectPass pass in basicEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
    {
        pass.Apply();
        GraphicsDevice.DrawPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 1);

    }
    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```